# How to locate the name, and list, of an array within an object in JavaScript using nested for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

So I have the following array of objects:

```
var data = [
    {
        "title": "scooter", 
        "materials": ["wood", "metal", "glass"]
    }, 
    {
        "title": "baseball bat", 
        "materials": ["wood", "metal"]
    },
    {
        "title": "coffee table", 
        "materials": ["wood"]
    }
];
```

Trying to get from a function the following:
From the materials array what has more than, or equal to, 2 materials and what are the items.

I've tried the following:

```
function testing() {
    let container = [];
    let items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        container.push(data[i].materials);
        for (let j = 0; j < container.length; j++) {
            if (container[i][j] >= 2) {
                items.push(data[i].title);
            }
        }
    }
    return(items);
}
console.log(testing());
```

I'm not able to get the nested array to check for length and return the title let alone the full list.

An example of what I want to see based on the criteria:

Scooter: "wood", "metal", "glass"
Baseball bat: "wood", metal"

What am I doing wrong with the code?

Comment: may be `Scooter: "wood", "metal", "glass"` should be an array?  `Scooter: ["wood", "metal", "glass"]`

Comment: Could you at first update your snippet and fix the syntax mistakes and unbalanced brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just test the material length through one loop !

```
let items = [];
for(let i=0 ; i<data.length; i++){
    if(data[i].materials.length >= 2){
        items.push(data[i].title);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Nailed it. I was over thinking it by a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var data = [{"title": "scooter", "materials":["wood","metal","glass"]}, {"title": "baseball bat", "materials":["wood","metal"]}, {"title": "coffee table", "materials":["wood"]}];

console.log(
  data.filter(obj => obj.materials.length >= 2)
)
```

Or to convert the result to key value based:

```js
var data = [{"title": "scooter", "materials":["wood","metal","glass"]}, {"title": "baseball bat", "materials":["wood","metal"]}, {"title": "coffee table", "materials":["wood"]}];

console.log(
  data.filter(obj => obj.materials.length >= 2).map(obj => ({[obj.title]: obj.materials}))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map function and a filter function to do this:

```
let result = data.map(elem => ({count: elem.materials.length, materials: elem.materials, title: elem.title })).filter(elem => elem.count >= 2);
```

This way you get an array containing objects in the form `{ count: 2, materials: ["wood", "metal"], title: "baseball bat" }`

Comment: Return an expression from arrow function, rather than object literal

Comment: @guest I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: At JavaScript at Answer `result` would be an array containing `undefined` elements `let arr = [{a:1}]; let res = arr.map(o => {b:1}); console.log(res) // [undefined]`, `res = arr.map(o => ({b:1})); console.log(res) // [{b:1}]`

Comment: @Kind that wouldn't work, =>{} would be like a braced lambda

Comment: @Kind here you go